# How to prove that two sets are equaivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

There's this book iI'm reading and its definition of two sets being equivalent is that they have to have a one-to-one correspondence.

So there's this question I'm trying to prove and it goes:

Prove that if $f:A\to B$ is a function defined on the countable set $A$ then the range of $f$ is countable.

So the book's hint is that I should show that the range is equivalent to a subset of $A$ and then use a corollary in the book that states: Every subset of a countable set is countable.

So here's my attempt:

Suppose $X\subseteq A$ then for every $x\in$$X$ there is some $f(x)\in B$ such that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$, hence $f^{-1}:f(A)\to X$ and since $f:A\to B$ and by the definition of equivalence there is a one-to-one correspondence between the two sets, thus $f(A)$ and $X$ are equivalent, as required. And by the corollary of Theorem 1.1 $X$ is countable and so it follows that $f(A)$ is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $y$ in the range of $f$ you can find some $x$ in $A$ such that $f(x)=y$. So just choose one and you are 'building' a function from the range to a subset of $A$. Set $A$ is countable, hence well-ordered (there is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ or some finite set). You can choose the 'smallest' $x$ with $f(x)=y$. This gives a bijection from the range to a subset of $A$. From here you can use the hint of the book.

Comment: Note: If you do it this way you will need the axiom of choice, or at least the axiom of countable choice.

Comment: Depending on the level of logical strictness imposed on OP by his textbook / teachers this might not work smoothly, seing as we don't know that the image is countable (that's what we're trying to prove), doing what you're doing more or less assumes the axiom of choice. I believe it's possible to do with only the induction principle if you go through $A$ sequentially, and keep the ones that give you a new value of $f$.

Comment: So what you're saying is that i shouldn't start with assuming that for every $x$$\in$$X$ there is a corresponding function that maps x to B

Comment: Set $A$ is countable wich means that there is a bijection onto it from $\mathbb{N}$ or a finite set. So $A$ is well-ordered. You can 'choose' the smallest $x$ with $f(x)=y$.

Comment: So choosing the smallest element means that the $f$ is one-to-one since a well ordered element has only one smallest element?

Comment: Let $\phi:A\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be a bijection. $f^{-1}\left(\left\{ y\right\} \right)\neq\emptyset$
for every $y$ in range $R$ of $f$ . It contains a unique element $x_{0}$
with $f\left(x\right)=y\Rightarrow\phi\left(x_{0}\right)\leq\phi\left(x\right)$.
Now define $g\left(y\right):=x_{0}$ and thus an injective function
$g:R\rightarrow A$ is constructed. Then there is bijection between
$R$ and $g\left(R\right)$. The set $g\left(R\right)$ is a subset
of countable $A$ hence countable (hint of book). Then $R$ is countable
as well.

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}$ need not exist.  As you are building your proof, make sure it works for the following two functions:

1: $f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(n)=|n|$.

2: $g:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(n)=3$.